# Can't get pointer to point to a node

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I am trying to create my own Binary Tree data structure.

I am using a `BinaryNode<T>` class as the leaves with a `BinaryNode<T>*` root to keep track of the root node.

```
template<class T>
class PPBinaryTree {
private:
    BinaryNode<T>* root;

public:
    PPBinaryTree();

    bool add(T Data, BinaryNode<T>* Root); 

    T* search(T Data, BinaryNode<T>* Root);  
};
```

Here is the implementation of the `add` function. No matter what I try I cannot create any new branches. The `RootProbe` seems to be a copy of the branch pointers so when I assign `Data` to it nothing changes in the branch.

The only solution I can think of is to change the line

```
RootProbe = (new BinaryNode<T>(Data));
```

to

```
*RootProbe = *(new BinaryNode<T>(Data));
```

but that just makes my program crash with an unhandled exception.

```
template<class T>
bool PPBinaryTree<T>::add(T Data, BinaryNode<T>* Root){
    bool isSuccessful = false;
    BinaryNode<T>* RootProbe;

    if(Root == NULL){
        Root = new BinaryNode<T>(Data);
        this->setRoot(Root);
        isSuccessful = true;
        return isSuccessful;
    }
    else{
        while(RootProbe != NULL){
            if(Data > Root->getData())
                RootProbe = Root->getRightBranch();
            else
                RootProbe = Root->getRightBranch();
        }
        RootProbe = (new BinaryNode<T>(Data));

        isSuccessful = true;
        return isSuccessful;
    }
}
```

Here is the `BinaryNode` class:

```
template<class S>
class BinaryNode {
private:
    S data;
    BinaryNode *leftBranch;
    BinaryNode *rightBranch;

public:
    BinaryNode(S data);

    void setData(S data);

    S getData( );

    void setLeftBranch(BinaryNode newNode);

    BinaryNode* getLeftBranch( );

    void setRightBranch(BinaryNode newNode);

    BinaryNode* getRightBranch( );
};
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you receive exception somewhere?

Comment: @Arkady _'RootProbe = (new BinaryNode(Data)); to *RootProbe = *(new BinaryNode(Data)); but that just makes my program crash with an unhandled exception.'_

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that:

```
while(RootProbe != NULL){
    if(Data > Root->getData())
        RootProbe = Root->getRightBranch();
    else
        RootProbe = Root->getRightBranch();
}
RootProbe = (new BinaryNode<T>(Data));
```

Have to be changed, to initialize RootProbe from right and **left** branches.
Also you forgot to set your RootProbe somewhere in the tree.

```
BinaryNode<T>* LastLiveProbe;
while(RootProbe != NULL){
    if(Data > Root->getData())
    {
        RootProbe = Root->getLeftBranch();
        if (RootProbe == NULL)
            LastLiveProbe->setLeftBranch(new BinaryNode<T>(Data));
        else
            LastLiveProbe = RootProbe;
    }
    else
    {
        RootProbe = Root->getRightBranch();
        if (RootProbe == NULL)
            LastLiveProbe->setRightBranch(new BinaryNode<T>(Data));
        else
            LastLiveProbe = RootProbe;
    }
}
```

If you don't have other problems, that should help.